# More elegant way of showing label depending of a number

Tags: c#

Is there a more elegant way of showing label depending of a number in C#? For example if number = 2, show only label1 and label2. So far I have this:

```
private void MakeLabelVisible(int number)
{
    switch (number)
    {
        case 0:
            lblLetter0.Visible = true;
            lblLetter0.Text = "";
            break;
        case 1:
            lblLetter1.Visible = true;
            lblLetter1.Text = "";
            break;
        case 2:
            lblLetter2.Visible = true;
            lblLetter2.Text = "";
            break;
        case 3:
            lblLetter3.Visible = true;
            lblLetter3.Text = "";
            break;
        case 4:
            lblLetter4.Visible = true;
            lblLetter4.Text = "";
            break;
        case 5:
            lblLetter5.Visible = true;
            lblLetter5.Text = "";
            break;
        case 6:
            lblLetter6.Visible = true;
            lblLetter6.Text = "";
            break;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: "*For example if number = 2, show only label1 and label2*" -  this is not what your code does

Comment: Put your controls in arrays, where the indexes match the control number. Use the `number` parameter as an index. Put comments in your code explaining that everything needs to be kept in sync, that the index is important, etc. You probably want to loop through the array and make everything `visible=false` before you start

Comment: Please specify UI, is it `WinForms`, `WPF`, something else?

Comment: `Text` and `Visible` - must be winforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have exactly 1 label for each number, you can use a list :

```
    private List<Label> _labels;

    private void InitLabels()
    {
        _labels = new List<Label>() { label1, label2, label3, label4, label5, label6 };
    }

    private void MakeLabelVisible(int number)
    {
        _labels[number].Visible = true;
        _labels[number].Text = "";
    }
```

Comment: You probably want to loop through `_labels` before you set one of their `Visibility` properties to `true` and set every control's `Visibility` to `false`. That way, only one is true at a time

Answer (score 1):

You can try *finding* `Label` by its name; in case of `WinForms` it can be (show only label `number`):

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 // show label # number only
 private void MakeLabelVisible(int number) {
   if (Controls.Find($"lblLetter{number}", true).FirstOrDefault() is Label lbl) {
     lbl.Visible = true;
     lbl.Text = ""; 
   }
 }
```

If you want to show labels *from* `0` up to and including `number`, just add *loop*:

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 // show labels ## 0..number
 private void MakeLabelVisible(int number) {
   for (int i = 0; i <= number; ++i) {       
     if (Controls.Find($"lblLetter{i}", true).FirstOrDefault() is Label lbl) {
       lbl.Visible = true;
       lbl.Text = ""; 
     }
   }
 }
```